# if input (checkbox) is disabled -> hide it's label

Tags: label, hide

I have the following code and would like to hide the label:

```
<div>  
<input type="checkbox" data-filter-value="17_72" class="attrib filterselector unav_option" name="filter[17]" id="filter_17_72" value="72" disabled="">
<label class="optionvalue" for="filter_17_72"> Some Text</label> </div>
```

There are several of these in my code and I'd like to have all the labels hidden where their input has the state disabled=""

Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve this. So it can be something like this

```
$(function () {
        if ($('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled')) {
            var hide = $('label').hide();
        }
});
```

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htg6Lxfm/5/)**

Comment: Many thanks again, but Firebug now tells me: TypeError: $(...).prop is not a function

Comment: Have you got jQuery library in your project? You can read the docs [Here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). You can also use `is` or `attr`

Comment: Yes, of course I have the jQuery library included (v1.4.2). I also tried is and attr with no success. The disabled input also has a class "unav_option" and I also tried to grab this via hasClass and then to add an extra class to the label.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get managed via JS so I tried via CSS and it works:

```
#filterForm input.unav_option + label {display:none !important;}
```